# Prolog - Recursive append to list returning false

Tags: prolog

Title says it all, but here we are again. Trying to append recursively to a list in Prolog, and while I have previously gotten it to work by having "temporary buffers" (via nb_setval/nb_getval) I'd like to learn how to, in a slightly more appropriate way, recursively append to lists.

I've understood Prolog works all around bindings and once something is bound it's difficult to manipulate it, so initially I sat with this, but I've understood why that does not quite work:

```
recursiveAppend([], _).
recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    append(H, [], Output),
    recursiveAppend(T, Output).
```

That made me change the code and go to the following:

```
recursiveAppend([], _).
recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).
```

Which I had hoped would work, as it made sense to myself and apparently to others while scouring other StackOverflow questions as well. Unfortunately, calling this predicate in SWI-Prolog only returns **false**.

`?- recursiveAppend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], L1). false`

Expected/desired result would, in this case, be:

`?- recursiveAppend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], L1). L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].`

For the sake of clarification, the runtime of the program should look something like this if "fleshed out":

```
recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    % H is 1, Output is []
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    % NewOutput is [1]
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).

recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    % H is 2, Output is [1]
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    % NewOutput is [1, 2]
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).

recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    % H is 3, Output is [1, 2]
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    % NewOutput is [1, 2, 3]
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).

recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    % H is 4, Output is [1, 2, 3]
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    % NewOutput is [1, 2, 3, 4]
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).

recursiveAppend([H|T], Output):-
    % H is 5, Output is [1, 2, 3, 4]
    append(H, Output, NewOutput),
    % NewOutput is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    recursiveAppend(T, NewOutput).

recursiveAppend([], _). % First argument (list) is empty, and the second argument (list) has been populated (with [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), program done.
```

Any and all help is appreciated, even though this question has probably been asked a million times before!

Comment: what is it appending? it's unclear. the example does not clarify: `recursiveAppend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], L1), L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].` can be simply coded as `recursiveAppend(A, L1) :- L1 = A.`. give more examples which can't be misinterpreted and show your intentions clearer please.

Comment: @WillNess Have expanded the question now, hopefully something that should be able to help you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: no, you haven't shown us "more examples" of input-output pairings which I asked for. "input" means "here's a test call I try at the REPL", "output" means "here's what I want to see it respond". you seem to not understand basic Prolog. start with tutorials from the very start. ask questions about each smallest possible thing you don't understand, don't be building castles on quicksand foundations and then ask us why this large structure isn't standing right, or at all. when you learn, verify every new step in your growing understanding by writing small programs and trying them at the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is a different programming paradigm. It requires you to "forget" all you know about programming and learn with an open mind. Don't try to learn Prolog while using "ordinary" variables and reaffecting different values, Prolog variables has only one value or none. They may take different values only on backtracking, and trying to find another set of values to all variables in your program that satisfies all the given predicates.

Suggest you to read books like "learn Prolog Now". Numerous tutorials from state universities are available free on the internet.

Based on your latest edit giving an example to Calling recursiveAppend, here's a code conform with the example.

```
recursiveAppend(X, Y) :- recursiveAppend(X, [], Y).

    recursiveAppend([], X, X).
    recursiveAppend([H|T], Current, Output):-
        append(Current, [H], NewTemp),
        recursiveAppend(T, NewTemp, Output).
```

Your earlier codes returned false because append expects lists as arguments. So appending an integer (item of input list) will Always fail. I created a version recursiveAppend/3 to accumulate current list in the second arg. At the end of the list, the current list becomes the final output. Will you test it further with more examples and tell us if it is working as required.

Comment: I did mention I want it to "recursively append"; but you are right it isn't exactly glass clear what I *actually* want it to do. Have now added a "expected/desired" "section" to the question, hopefully that helps?

Comment: Give one or more examples

Comment: Please do correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe I have? I've got code snippets with the code, the exact line I'm using to call the predicate, and the expected/desired as well as current result? It's not necessarily part of a larger portion of code but rather one small task to step-by-step learn how to do things so I don't know what else I can give you.

Comment: I don't believe saying "forget everything you know" is helpful. I know it's a popular saying, but still, we could instead say that Prolog-as-functional-language substrate is a set-once language with named pointers, without nested scope, built around state-passing paradigm.

Comment: @peter.cyc Have now tested the code you provided, and as far as I can tell, it is very much doing what I want it to do. I also like your answer because (I believe) I see why my solution failed where your solution succeeded. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"Recursive append" is not something that often makes sense in Prolog. The question should include information about *what problem you are trying to solve*. Currently it is not about that; it is about *how you are trying to solve your problem*. That "how" is "recursive append", but this is almost certainly not how you should really solve that problem. We could offer better help if we knew what *the problem* was, not how you think you want to solve it.

Taking the example from the question and the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64092447/4391743:

```
?- recursiveAppend([1, 2, 3], Ys).
Ys = [1, 2, 3].

?- recursiveAppend(Xs, [1, 2, 3]).
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
% nontermination after first answer

?- recursiveAppend([1, 2, X], [A, B, 3]).
X = 3,
A = 1,
B = 2.

?- recursiveAppend([1, 2 | Rest], [A, B, 3, 4]).
Rest = [3, 4],
A = 1,
B = 2 ;
% nontermination after first answer
```

If this is what you want, then what you seem to want is a "list copy" predicate. Here's a shorter, faster, more complete one:

```
list_copy([], []).
list_copy([X | Xs], [X | Ys]) :-
    list_copy(Xs, Ys).
```

This doesn't have the non-termination issues that the above predicate has:

```
?- list_copy([1, 2, 3], Ys).
Ys = [1, 2, 3].

?- list_copy(Xs, [1, 2, 3]).
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- list_copy([1, 2, X], [A, B, 3]).
X = 3,
A = 1,
B = 2.

?- list_copy([1, 2 | Rest], [A, B, 3, 4]).
Rest = [3, 4],
A = 1,
B = 2.
```

If one of the arguments is a list and the other is a variable, a new list structure will be built up and bound to this variable.

But... why do you need a new list structure at all? In pure Prolog you can't tell whether two terms are *the same* (i.e., sharing the same memory location) or "just" structurally equal. Neither do (or *should*) you usually care. (There are uses for knowledge about sharing, and about explicit copying, in non-pure Prolog, but again we don't know what you're trying to do.)

So if we can't tell whether a "copy" is indeed a copy or just "an equal term", then we don't need to copy at all. We can get the exact same behavior as above with just unification:

```
?- [1, 2, 3] = Ys.
Ys = [1, 2, 3].

?- Xs = [1, 2, 3].
Xs = [1, 2, 3].

?- [1, 2, X] = [A, B, 3].
X = 3,
A = 1,
B = 2.

?- [1, 2 | Rest] = [A, B, 3, 4].
Rest = [3, 4],
A = 1,
B = 2.
```

No copying and certainly no "recursive append" is needed to achieve unification, Prolog knows how to do unification for you.

If this is not what you want, please tell us what the actual problem is. "Recursive append" is almost certainly not it.

Comment: BTW OP's code could be tweaked with [same-length tracking to improve termination](https://pastebin.com/SETef7qE). with it, `recursiveAppend(Xs, [1, 2, 3]).` fails on backtracking. for some reason there's still the choice point hanging there though, unlike with your `list_copy/2`, which _is_ the proper way to do that kind of thing anyway, top-down, linearly, as Prolog is so good at with its tail-rec-mod-cons; a.o.t. the quadratic repeated append. but of course for *that* kind of discussion the OP should've been after some understanding, not just working code. :|

Comment: (putting that additional argument into the 1st position [fixed that problem](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/same-length-tracking.pl).)

Comment: Thanks for these experiments. Weirdly, putting the SameLength tracking into argument positions 1, 2, or 3 fixes the choice point, but having it in argument position 4 leaves the choice open. SWI was easier to understand when it only indexed on the first argument.

Comment: yeah, this depends on the version, indeed. locally, I have a pretty old version installed, and it didn't work even with the 2nd.  :)

Comment: I guess there is/was no point or problem present at any point, but rather just an exercise to see how Prolog handles recursion and lists (creating a program that counts in Prolog is very easy even to me, but I started realising I had more things to think about the second lists were introduced). I'm still very new to Prolog but slowly trying to get some kind of grasp on how things work (and doesn't work), as compared to OOP.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Xariez I see. The general pattern for recursion on lists is as in my `list_copy` predicate: Unification in the clause head serves both to *match* and to *construct* lists. In many cases this replaces "append" operations. To practice this pattern, try implementing `list_doubled` such that `list_doubled([a, b, c], Doubled)` succeeds with `Doubled = [a, a, b, b, c, c]`, and `list_halved` such that `list_halved([a, b, c, d, e], Halved)` succeeds with `Halved = [a, c]`. For both predicates, check what happens when you specify a list in the second argument and a variable in the first!

Comment: I'll have a look/shot at it as soon as I get an opportunity with everything else going on at the moment.  Still, thank you, again, for your answers! @IsabelleNewbie