# finding a cycle path in prolog

Tags: prolog, path-finding

[image]

```
atom_elements(h1,hydrogen,[c1]).
atom_elements(n1,nitrogen,[o1, o2, c2]).
atom_elements(o1,oxygen,[n1]).
atom_elements(o2,oxygen,[n1]).
atom_elements(n2,nitrogen,[o3, o4, c4]).
atom_elements(o3,oxygen,[n2]).
atom_elements(o4,oxygen,[n2]).
atom_elements(h5,hydrogen,[c5]).
atom_elements(n3,nitrogen,[o5, o6, c6]).
atom_elements(o5,oxygen,[n3]).
atom_elements(o6,oxygen,[n3]).
atom_elements(h7,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(h8,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(h9,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(c1,carbon,[c2,c6,h1]).
atom_elements(c2,carbon,[c1,c3,n1]).
atom_elements(c3,carbon,[c2,c7,c4]).
atom_elements(c4,carbon,[c3,c5,n2]).
atom_elements(c5,carbon,[c4,c6,h5]).
atom_elements(c6,carbon,[c1,c5,n3]).
atom_elements(c7,carbon,[c3,h7,h8,h9]).
```

Example query on the 2,4,6-Trinitrotoluene:

```
?- tnt(X).
X = [[c1, [c2, n1, o1, o2], c3, [c4, n2, o3, o4], c5,
[c6, n3, o5, o6]]] .
```

My first step is to find a cycle path and show as a List. But the result is shown as **fault**. It cannot save the path as a list.

```
atom_elements(h1,hydrogen,[c1]).
atom_elements(n1,nitrogen,[o1, o2, c2]).
atom_elements(o1,oxygen,[n1]).
atom_elements(o2,oxygen,[n1]).
atom_elements(n2,nitrogen,[o3, o4, c4]).
atom_elements(o3,oxygen,[n2]).
atom_elements(o4,oxygen,[n2]).
atom_elements(h5,hydrogen,[c5]).
atom_elements(n3,nitrogen,[o5, o6, c6]).
atom_elements(o5,oxygen,[n3]).
atom_elements(o6,oxygen,[n3]).
atom_elements(h7,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(h8,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(h9,hydrogen,[c7]).
atom_elements(c1,carbon,[c2,c6,h1]).
atom_elements(c2,carbon,[c1,c3,n1]).
atom_elements(c3,carbon,[c2,c7,c4]).
atom_elements(c4,carbon,[c3,c5,n2]).
atom_elements(c5,carbon,[c4,c6,h5]).
atom_elements(c6,carbon,[c1,c5,n3]).
atom_elements(c7,carbon,[c3,h7,h8,h9]).

removeprevious(X,Y):-
    X=Y.

filterList(A,In,Out) :-
    exclude(removeprevious(A),In,Out).

nextlist(P,C,O) :-
    atom_elements(C,_,L),
    filterList(P,L,O).

findTNT(Start,Output):-
    atom_elements(Start,_,List),
    findTNT(Start,Start,List,[],Output).
    
findTNT(_,_,[],_,[]).
findTNT(Start,_,[H|_],_,Output) :-
    H = Start,
    write('Find it'),   %For debugging%
    append([H],[],Output).

findTNT(Start,Privious,[H|T],Visited,Output) :-
    write(H+'--'), %For debugging%
    H \== Start,
    \+ member(H,Visited),
    nextlist(Privious,H,List),
    append([H],Visited,V),
    (   
    findTNT(Start,H,List,V,Output),
        Output = [],
        findTNT(Start,Privious,T,V,Output);
        append([H],Output,O),
        Output is O).
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: Can you narrow down your code for noobs in organic chemistry ? Which predicate is giving you problem ?

Comment: You defined removeprevious/2, but used removeprevious/1 in filterList/3. Something's wrong !

Comment: Thank you for reply, the main problem is occurred at right after ‘write(‘Find it’)’, it couldn’t append the output list. 
Another problem is I am not sure that, is the recursion work in the way which find the same node after a cycle, then at the Node return a list. The upper recursion check if the list empty, if not, append the current node and return recursively. BTW, the removeprevious/2 used in filterList/3 seems no error.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not very good, but it indicates that the problem is with your use of `is`. Concretely, line 65 of your code reads:

```
Output is O
```

At the problematic point in the program, `Output` is `[]` and `O` is `[c6]`, which is why this goal is printed as

```
[] is [c6]
```

So the problem is that you are using `is` on something that is not an arithmetic expression. `is` is **only** usable for evaluating arithmetic, for example:

```
X is 2 + 2
```

It is **not** usable for equality of terms. Use `=` for that. So this last line should maybe be something more like:

```
Output = O
```

Except that that will also not work, because you are trying to "assign" a new term to a variable that is already bound to a different term. And you're trying to do "recursive append", which is something that is pretty much always wrong in Prolog. Some recent questions about this: [Prolog - Recursively append numbers to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830002/prolog-recursively-append-numbers-to-a-list), [Prolog - Recursive append to list returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092046/prolog-recursive-append-to-list-returning-false)