# Prolog - Recursively append numbers to a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I am just starting to learn Prolog, and I am having troubles wrapping my head around recursive concepts. Right now, solely for the purpose of practice, I am trying to write a program that appends 10 numbers to a list and then prints out that list.

The self-imposed rule for this program is that the list has to be 'declared' (I am not sure if that is the correct word for Prolog) in a main predicate, which calls another predicate to append numbers to the list.

This is what I have so far, and I know it won't work because I am trying to redefine `List` at the end of the `addToList` predicate, which is not allowed in the language.

```
% Entry point that declares a list (`List`) to store the 10 numbers
printList(List) :-
    addToList(0, List),
    writeln(List).

% Base case - once we hit 11 we can stop adding numbers to the list
addToList(11, _).

% First case - this predicate makes adding the first number easier for me...
addToList(0, List) :-
    append([], [0], NewList),
    addToList(1, NewList),
    append([],  NewList, List). % This is valid, but List will just be [0] I think..

% Cases 1-10
addToList(Value, List) :-
    append(List, [Value], NewList),
    NextVal is Value+1,
    addToList(NextVal, NewList),
    append([], NewList, List). % This is INVALID since List is already defined
```

This program would be started with:

```
printList(List).
```

Is there a simple way to change up the broken program I have written up to make it work correctly? I am super lost on how to get the numbers stored in `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking procedurally, in prolog you cannot change variables. You are trying to construct the list yourself. In prolog-style you try to declare the constraints of the list you want. If `nlist/2` is a predicate that gives a list of N numbers then what exactly are it's properties? `nlist(0, []).` and if `nlist(N, Xs)` then `nlist(N+1, [N+1 | Xs])`. So you just write these and let prolog take care of the construction.

```
nlist(0, []).
nlist(N, [N | Xs]) :-
    N>0, N1 is N-1,
    nlist(N1, Xs).
```

If you are confused how the recursion calls are taking place, try using `trace/0` or `trace/1`. You can see how the calls are being done in the following trace. You can get this by calling `trace(nlist)`.

```
?- nlist(3, X).
 T Call: nlist(3, _78)
 T Call: nlist(2, _902)
 T Call: nlist(1, _1464)
 T Call: nlist(0, _2026)
 T Exit: nlist(0, [])
 T Exit: nlist(1, [1])
 T Exit: nlist(2, [2, 1])
 T Exit: nlist(3, [3, 2, 1])
X = [3, 2, 1]
```

A more procedural style code will be as follows

```
addToList(11, A, A).

% Cases 1-10
addToList(Value, List, NewList) :-
    Value < 11,  append(List, [Value], Temp),
    NextVal is Value+1,
    addToList(NextVal, Temp, NewList).
```

This gives the middle parameter is the accumulator. When you reach 11 the accumulator is the answer.

```
?- addToList(1, [], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...] 

?- addToList(5, [], X).
X = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Look at the sample trace and the difference between them in `nlist` and `addToList`. Try to figure out the differences and why the are happening.

```
?- addToList(7, [], X).
 T Call: addToList(7, [], _33565254)
 T Call: addToList(8, [7], _33565254)
 T Call: addToList(9, [7, 8], _33565254)
 T Call: addToList(10, [7, 8, 9], _33565254)
 T Call: addToList(11, [7, 8, 9, 10], _33565254)
 T Exit: addToList(11, [7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10])
 T Exit: addToList(10, [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10])
 T Exit: addToList(9, [7, 8], [7, 8, 9, 10])
 T Exit: addToList(8, [7], [7, 8, 9, 10])
 T Exit: addToList(7, [], [7, 8, 9, 10])
X = [7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this response. Your solution is simple and understandable. Getting myself to escape my procedural thinking is going to be tough as I continue to learn Prolog..

Comment: You will slowly get used to it. You can write procedural style code too, but you will be fighting against the prolog environment rather than letting it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
printSeries(_,[],0):-!.
printSeries(S,[S|T],C):-
    S1 is S+1,
    C1 is C-1,
    printSeries(S1,T,C1).

?- printSeries(7,L,5).
L = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

The predicate can be used to print any series using a starting number and how many times one wants to increment it. A very easy approach is using counter. The first predicate is saying that regardless of the starting number, and whatever is in the list, if the counter reaches 0 the program should cut (meaning stop). The second predicate we have the starting number, and the list to which we are telling it that you have to start the list with the starting number, and lastly the counter. Next we increment the starting number by 1. Decrease the counter by 1. Then redo everything by giving the new values to the predicate.

```
?-printSeries(1,L,10).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```